# CakePHP 3 - Unable to add new record

Tags: forms, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

When i submit new Job form, hte action passes all the info to the url but the saving action is not happening and no flash message for success or error.

In variable tab in the debugkit all looks ok except maybe the id but it should auto increment anyway...

```
job (array)
    [new] (true) 
        [accessible] (array) 
            * (true)
            id (false)
```

The edit Job method works well.

add Job function

```
public function add()
{
        $job = $this->Jobs->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $job = $this->Jobs->patchEntity($job, $this->request->getData());
            $job->user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
            if ($this->Jobs->save($job)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Job hasbeen saved'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Please try again'));            
        }

        $categories = $this->Jobs->Categories->find('list');
        $users = $this->Jobs->Users->find('list');
        $types = $this->Jobs->Types->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('job', 'categories', 'users', 'types'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['job']);
    }
```

view

```
<div class="col_12 column">
    <form id="reg_form">    
        <fieldset>
            <legend><?= __('Add Job') ?></legend>
            <?php
                echo $this->Form->create($job);
                echo $this->Form->control('category_id', ['options' => $categories]);           
                echo $this->Form->control('user_id', ['options'=>$users]);
                echo $this->Form->control('type_id', ['options' => $types]);
                echo $this->Form->control('company_name');
                echo $this->Form->control('title');
                echo $this->Form->control('description');
                echo $this->Form->control('area');
                echo $this->Form->control('city');
                echo $this->Form->control('contact_email');
                echo $this->Form->button(__('Submit'));
                echo $this->Form->end();
          ?>
        </fieldset>   
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: seems you are passing your data via get parameters but then in your controller you only accept post data. Change your form or your controller. Why don't you use the form helper?

Comment: you so right! i'v deleted the original form tags wich genereted by composer and forgot to add in the new form tags- method="post"..

Comment: You shouldn't add any `<form>` tags at all, that's what the form helper will generate.

Comment: Why you using `<form>` and `echo $this->Form->create($job);`. This will create a form inside another. You have to use one. In your question do you say that you pass all the data to the url so you have to use the GET method and not POST inside your controller function. I think that when you use only `echo $this->Form->create($job);` the form is automatic set to use the POST method and your function will be work.